# OpenRISC GCC Access special registers

Tags: gcc

How to access OpenRISC special registers (l.mtspr/l.mfspr) from C code if i am using [openrisc gcc](https://opencores.org/or1k/OpenRISC_GNU_tool_chain)?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem that you're trying to solve? *Why* do you need those registers? Your question is a very good example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I have a OpenRISC (on FPGA) and i am trying to create my own OS from sctrach for it. It does not have same special registers architecture as usual OpenRISC cores.

Comment: That information should really be in the question body (please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Anyway, it doesn't matter since you can not access the CPU registers directly in standard C anyway. With GCC you could use *inline assembler* to copy a registers value to a C variable. It is an extension of GCC (and most other major compilers have similar extensions). You could try to read up about that.

Comment: I totally forgot about inline assembler. Thx :). Can i use [Explicit Register Variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html) ?